# how to make icon with Icon width color

Tags: flutter

i need to make one icon like star border icon with percentage width or height color.

I need this kind of icon for the ranking system.

for example if rating is 4, 80% of this icon get yellow background color.

thank

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stack` widget as follows:

[image: stack visual]

You can set the width of second container to the % you want, after calculation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MyApp "),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 50.0,
                width: 50.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50.0,
                width: 40.0,  // calculate this value from the %
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
               Container(
                height: 50.0,
                width: 50.0,
                 child: Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above gives output: [image: output]

Comment: thank for your answer, but I did this before and the reality is not very interesting and I do not like it

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about look and feel of UI, instead of just being dismissive of the overall approach :), then you can have a look at this [liquid_progress_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_progress_indicator) package in pub.dev.